# What about the convergence of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\frac{\lambda(n)}{\operatorname{rad}(n)}\log\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Let $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ the product of distinct primes dividing $n>1$, with the definition $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$ (if you need it, see the definition of the radical of an integer from this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer)). Also we consider the Liouville function $\lambda(n)$ (see its definition from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvilleFunction.html)).

> **Question (I changed the question; I've decided it, see the comments)** Is it possible to deduce if $$\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\frac{\lambda(n)}{\operatorname{rad}(n)}\log\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\tag{1}$$
>   does converge as $x\to\infty$? **Thanks in advance.**

I don't know if this question was in the literature, if it is known refers the literature and I try to find and read it. I've created this question as an analogous question from a Math Overflow post.

If my reasoning is right I can to find the Euler product of (I know how to calculate the Euler product and its derivative) $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda(n)}{\operatorname{rad}(n)}\frac{1}{n^s}\tag{2}$$
for $\Re s>\sigma$ and to find the derivative $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda(n)}{\operatorname{rad}(n)}\frac{\log n}{n^s}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: The definitions of those functions imply $\displaystyle\frac{\mu(n)}{\operatorname{rad}(n)}=\frac{\mu(n)}n$ for every natural $n$, meaning that's all well known.

Comment: Now I see (from your words) that this question is bad. Many thanks @ProfessorVector